# Approach to write dynamic query using spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently I am using below query to achieve the requirement. But now, a new requirement has come where in 7 new filter criteria is to be added to this query. 2 of these filter require additional joins to table. All these filter are non-mandatory and they can be applied in conjunction.

My question is how should I tackle this requirement. Initially I was thinking to writing a single query in such a way that would have all filters with all joins on table but this would not be performance friendly. Also I am new to Spring JPA. So, if anyone has fulfilled such requirement in past, request you to share how it was achieved or if someone have suggestion as to how this can be achieved, request you to share.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT "
    + "a.GROUP_REF_ID as refId "
    + "count(case when c.STAT_CD in :userStatus then (c.grp_user_id) end) as numberOfUsers, "
    + "count(case when b.STAT_CD in :itemStatus then (b.grp_item_id) end) as numberOfItems  "
    + "from grp a left join grp_item b on a.grp_id=b.grp_id left join grp_user c on a.grp_id=c.grp_id "
    + "where a.stat_cd in :status and a.co_id in :cids "
    + "group by a.GROUP_REF_ID,a.grp_nam,a.GRP_DESC,a.co_id,a.co_nam,a.CRTE_BY, "
    + "a.CRTE_DT,a.UPDT_BY,a.UPDT_DT ", countQuery = "select count(*) from grp where stat_cd in :status and co_id in :cids ", nativeQuery = true)
public Page<Object> findByStatusAndCompanyIdIn(@Param("status") String status, @Param("cids") List<Long> companyIds,
    @Param("userStatus") List<GroupUserStatus> userStatus,
    @Param("itemStatus") List<GroupItemStatus> itemStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data JPA provides convenient use of [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications), which is perfectly suitable for filtering.

Define your specifations such as (add one per filter, join tables as needed per specification):

```
public static Specification<Grp> status(final String status) {
    // EQUAL clause
    return (grp, query, cb) -> cb.equal(grp.<String>get("status"), status);
}

public static Specification<Grp> companyIds(final List<Long> companyIds) {
    // IN clause
    return (grp, query, cb) -> grp.<Long>get("co_id").in(companyIds);
}
```

Then combine specifications:

```
Specifications<Grp> spec = Specifications.where(status(myStatus))
                                         .and(companyIds(myCompanyIds));
```

Finally read the data:

```
List<Grp> grps = grpRepository.findAll(spec);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read about it and found that we can also use query-dsl for this. What's your opinion. Should I go for specification or query-dsl. Which will be a good option for performance perspective

Comment: SO isn't a site to express opinions, but solutions to specific problems. QueryDSL is also a potential solution.